# How to record single app windows on ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, display, vlc-media-player, xorg, recording

I started using ffmpeg to record screen, but the manual do not provides any way to record a single window app on xorg interaction.

Well, i know it's possible because VLC does it. Does anyone know how to do it via -i (input) argument on ffmpeg?
thanks

PS: I'm on Arch, i3wm.